# Synchronization between two same databases in SQL Server and Firebird

Tags: sql-server-2005, firebird

I have same databases in SQL Server2005 and Firebird, how can i synchronize these two databases.
   My application is there in both window base and web base, some features in window application and some other features in web application. for window application we are using firebird2.5.0 and for web application SQLServer2005.  If any changes occur in SQL database through web application, same changes must happen firebird database also. like that if any changes in firebird database then same changes must happen in SQL database also. how its possible.

Comment: Question is not clear:edition of SQLServer;online only or offline synchronization type.

Comment: Also, let us know the direction of synchronization: **FB -> SQL** or **FB <- SQL** or **FB <-> SQL**?

Answer (score 0):

I think [CopyTiger](http://copycat-replication.com/feature-list/copytiger-feature-list.html) can help you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of synchronization rules, I might find yourself having to implement/code that. I'm sure there are tools for sync, but I'm also pretty sure that tools seldom resolve complex issues.

There are tons of ways of doing this. We would need to know more details of your structure and environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Daffodil Replicator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/daffodilreplica/) supports both Firebird and MS SQL.